# return type of SqlDataReader method

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sqldatareader

I have a method inside a class, that contains SqlDataReader(it connects to a database table and retrieves a number of rows). 
later i want to assign each record that SqlDataReader has, to asp labels . but i don't know what should be the return type of a method , so i can extract the values from it, and how to do that in code behind file.
here is the code;

```
 public (???) displayCustoemrhShipOrder()
    {
        string htmlStr = string.Empty;                   
        string sConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LGDB"].ToString();
        SqlConnection SqlCOn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString);
        SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand();
        SqlCmd.Connection = SqlCOn;
        SqlCmd.CommandText = "displayCustomerShipOrder";
        SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlCOn.Open();
        SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ShipOrderID",shipOrderID);
        SqlDataReader reader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            htmlStr = reader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
        }
        reader.Close();
        SqlCOn.Close();            
        return(???)
    }
```

Comment: in the presentation layer, i want assign data retrieved by data reader to asp labels!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you should never return `SqlDataReader` to a layer outside of your database-access code. The reason behind this general principle is that `SqlDataReader` is a very "expensive" object that **keeps an open connection to the database**! So if you keep a `SqlDataReader` around, it's not so bad, but if you keep 10 lying around at any given time? what about 100 of them? 1000? It's a recipe for disaster.

So how do you close the connection to the database from a SqlDataReader? .NET has a very handy methods in the `IDisposable` interface called `Dispose()` that will take care of the cleanup for you. So your code might looks like

```
function getData()
{
    // instantiate SqlDataReader from SqlCommand, call it "rdr"
    rdr.Dispose();
}
```

But actually there's an issue with that code. What if your code throws an exception before it gets to `Dispose()`? It should really look like

```
function getData()
{
    try{
        // instantiate SqlDataReader from SqlCommand, call it "rdr"
    }
    catch(Exception){}
    Finally{
        rdr.Dispose();
    }
}
```

That's very verbose! What if you don't want to type all that? Don't worry, .NET handled this for you as well. Do this:

```
public (???) displayCustoemrhShipOrder()
{
    string htmlStr = string.Empty;                   
    string sConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LGDB"].ToString();
    using(SqlConnection SqlCOn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString))
    {
    using(SqlCommand SqlCmd = new SqlCommand())
    {
    SqlCmd.Connection = SqlCOn;
    SqlCmd.CommandText = "displayCustomerShipOrder";
    SqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    SqlCOn.Open();
    SqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ShipOrderID",shipOrderID);
    using(SqlDataReader reader = SqlCmd.ExecuteReader())
    while (reader.Read())
    {
        htmlStr = reader.GetInt32(0).ToString();
    }
    // reader.Close();  // this line becomes optional, Dispose() will call Close()
    }
    // SqlCOn.Close();  // this line becomes optional, Dispose() will call Close()
    }
    }

    return(???)
}
```

This is all a roundabout way of saying that if you know you need to `Dispose()` and `Close()` the SqlDataReader, and that you cannot get data out of it once you do that, then you obviously should not return it to code what needs to work with the data (but not necessarily the database connection that it was taking up). I suggest using a `DataTable` class, you can read about it here:

[.NET DataTable class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx)

Also the method to convert to a `DataTable` is called `DataTable.Load(SqlDatareader...`

Comment: thank you so much for your comprehensive answer, it's very useful for a beginner like me. but later i want to assign data from data reader to asp labels, is it true to use a Data table class?

Comment: The Database access class can return a `DataTable` class instance, you can then convert that `DataTable` instance into whatever you want by iterating over `DataTable.Rows`, which is exactly like `DataReader.Read()` except that it will not consume an open database connection. This is a little inefficient because you are doing 2 iterations over your data, one in the `DataReader` to make the `DataTable` and one in the `DataTable` to make your `List<YourObjectWhichYouWillPassToAspLabel>`. You can skip the DataTable class by directly instantiating `YourObject...` from the data in `DataReader.Read`

Comment: But I don't recommend that until you have a little more experience because keeping the `DataReader` open for longer, or even the risk of keeping it open for longer has potentially huge downsides for not that much gain

Answer (score 1):

You can add each individual value to `List<string>` return it and use outside of the method.